# Apply a formula to an entire column since the number of rows is changing from a source file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a connection to a text file source so the excel worksheet updates automatically. Therefore the number of rows is always growing every time it updates. How can I apply a formula to an entire column?

Double clicking the box at the bottom corner of the cell only applies the formula to the previous cells before the connection refreshes, and the newly added rows at the bottom don't receive the formula.

Comment: You could fill the entire column with a formula and make it not display anything if the row it's on is empty. Otherwise if that's not an option, I'd say you'd need VBA.

Comment: I think I already tried what you mentioned: `=IF(A1<>"",C1/B1,"")`. Incredibly slow when the source updates and ends up filling the cells after the last row with "#REF". I don't know how to use VBA yet.

Comment: Ok... I don't know enough VBA either to help you on this problem. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you :)

Comment: I think you need to share the VBa code

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't state what formula you want to apply and reads how you can apply a formula for an entire column when the number of rows is unknown.

A few ideas

```
Range("A:A") 'this grabs the entire range
```

So, you could do

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:C2")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell in row.Cells
    'logic
  Next cell
Next row
```

Or, you could keep going to the next row until the next row is empty

```
dim row as integer
row = 1

do while (Range("A" & row).value<>"")
    'logic
    row= row + 1
loop
```

Your question also indicates that it's only doing the entire worksheet when you first load it, after, when you hit your button it doesn't apply it to new entries. This means it's not counting the total number of rows correctly, so you may be able to use something like the above to ensure it always iterates through all rows.